# Controlling how a custom class is sorted / indexed?

Tags: python, class, sorting, dictionary, attributes

I am attempting to represent a calendar in a Class-based format.

Currently, the data is represented in an OrderedDict of the following form:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictionary = OrderedDict()
dictionary[date] = {'attr1': ... ,
                    'attr2': ... ,
                    ... }
```

I would ideally like to instantiate some sort of `EnhancedDay` class which represents the data in the dictionary, with a corresponding `EnhancedCalendar` class that holds a sorted container (list, OrderedDict?) of `EnhancedDay`s. Features I'm looking at:

1. a number of `EnhancedDay` objects to be stored, ***sorted***, as `EnhancedCalendar.attr`
2. ability to retrieve / work with `EnhancedDay`s by date (i.e. I would like to use the date as a sort of 'key' so I could retrieve an `EnhancedDay` through something similar to `EnhancedCalendar.attr[date]`
3. a way to append/modify attributes of `EnhancedDay` instances which are stored as part of a `EnhancedCalendar` instance so that if I were to attempt to ***add*** an `EnhancedDay` to `EnhancedCalendar.attr` where there already was an `EnhancedDay` object in `EnhancedCalendar.attr` representing that date, the `EnhancedDay` object would instead be merged "automatically."

I think for #1, I basically understand the answer:

1. I would use the `@total_ordering` decorator (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering), specify an `__eq__` and other comparison operator to use the `EnhancedDay`'s `date` attr, and be good-to-go.
2. No idea. There are a few posts on SO on this topic, but I haven't found any that meet my needs.
3. The best way I know would be to write a custom merging function (something akin to a custom_append). `EnhancedCalendar.attr[date].custom_append(EnhancedDay)` and have a merge occur OR if `attr[date]` doesn't exist, create `attr[date]` Again, not sure of the **best/smoothest** way to do this. I'd love to use `+=`.

Also: what would be the best datatype to store the `EnhancedDay` instances in, in the `EnhancedCalendar` instance?

Alternatively, given what I'm trying to accomplish, some of my thinking might just be... off. Any help on that front would be appreciated.

Alternatively, this all may be way more trouble than it's worth, in which case I'm still interested in how you would theoretically accomplish these things using classes.

Answer (score 1):

For #2 There are a few ways to do this. One way might be to convert the date to some sort of canonical format, then use that as a string index into a dictionary.

For #3 take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence

It makes sure you implement the functions required for indexing and `+=` operators to work the way you want. Specifically for `+=` to work you need to override the `__iadd__()` function. 
For `Calendar[date]` to do what you want you'll need to override the `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` functions -- however collections.DefaultDict nearly does what you want there so I might be tempted to base EnhancedCalendar off of that.

I think I would use a list datatype to store the days inside the calendar, then you would index by day-1.

Comment: Thank you :). I'm using datetime.date as the canonical format for the index -- given that, would you be able to elaborate on your last sentance? I thought about DefaultDict, but iirc it was non-trivial to have a ***sorted*** DefaultDict.

Comment: I see. Does it need to be sorted? If you say EnhancedCalendar[0] it will return the first day of the calendar (unclear to me if a calendar is 1 month or 1 year or something else). If you want to use is as an iterator, then you could override `__iter__()` to iterate over them in whichever order you need.

Comment: Oh, that's cool. I think for speed, being sorted would be best (generally I'm iterating from earliest to latest).

`EnhancedCalendar` actually stores more data than just the dates information; just to be clear I'm interpreting where you wrote `EnhancedCalendar[0]` above to be `EnhancedCalendar.attr[0]`?

The idea is that it's a specialized calendar that covers an arbitrary range of (continuous) dates.